# Breaking BITSTREAM in to Multiple parts using WMB/ESQL

Tags: ibm-mq, sap-ase

I have a BITSTREAM from XML message. An I want to break in to multiple parts of equal size depending upon of the length of stream using ESQL i.e. if my bitstream 1000 characters I want to break it in to 200character equal sets. And late I want to pass this parts to a store procedure to insert or update the table.  I have BITSREAM Something like this
DECLARE vBlobMsgBody        BLOB;

```
        DECLARE refIn               REFERENCE TO    Environment.OriginalXML;
        DECLARE vEncoding           INT             InputRoot.Properties.Encoding;
        DECLARE vCCSID              INT             InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId;

        DECLARE vMsgBitStream BLOB ASBITSTREAM(refIn,1208);
```

How I will be to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same function of CHARACTER variables. 
SO you can use functions like:

DECLARE BLOB_LENGTH INTEGER LENGTH(vMsgBitStream); 
DECLARE FIRST_PART BLOB SUBSTRING(vMsgBitStream FROM 1 FOR 200);